# Regexp syntax MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

```
input1 = ' 8 BKN 15 BKN '  
input2 = ' 2 X 3SM ' 

regexp(input1, '\s{1}\d(1|2)\s{1}c{3}\s{1}')
regexp(input2, ''\s{1}\d(1|2)\c{1}\s{1}c{1}\s{1}' )
```

Have trouble getting regexp to work. I'm not at all great a debugging.

The code needs to identify (one space, (one digit or two digits), one space, three characters `[A-Z]`, and one space)

The code needs  (one space, one digit or two digits, one space, X the letter, one digit and two characters, and one space)

Comment: show the output you are getting and what's your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the two settings below (I don't have MatLab but your question is really on regular expressions):

Condition 1 (try it here: https://regex101.com/r/Bvp3ct/2):

```
^[ ]\d{1,2}[ ][A-Z]{3}[ ]
```

Condition 2: (try it here: https://regex101.com/r/Bvp3ct/4):

```
[ ]\d{1,2}[ ][X][ ]\d{1}[A-Z]{2}[ ]
```

It is unclear if the string needs to start at the beginning of the line (add or remove the ^ at the beginning as needed. Keep it if it must start at the beginning of the line.

There is a legend on the lower right of the site I linked to for the examples that breaks down the notation as well.